# Error importing jpype module

Tags: python, jpype

Could someone please advise in resolving the below error?
Python 3.5.1 / jpype1-py3 0.5.5.2 installed on 64 bit windows machine.
I've cannot find _jtype anywhere in Lib or Lib/site-packages.

Regards
Steve

```
>>> import jpype
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import jpype
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\jpype\__init__.py", line 18, in 
    from ._jpackage import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jpackage.py", line 18, in 
    import _jpype
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: How do you know it is installed? Do you know where it is installed?

Comment: Did you installed via pip? This lib is in site-packages?

Comment: @Tales its installed via pip and I can see the lib folder in Lib/site-packages.

Comment: @tmthydvnprt when I run pip search jpype, its returns : INSTALLED: 0.5.5.2 (latest). I can see the module in Lib/site-packages

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/jpype/discussion/379372/thread/2f54b1b1/) thread, you need to make sure setup.py is pointing to the correct jvm directory. looking into setup.py of you can see that it searches for JAVA_HOME system variable:

```
java_home = os.getenv('JAVA_HOME', '')
found_jni = False
if os.path.exists(java_home):
    platform_specific['include_dirs'] += [os.path.join(java_home, 'include')]
# The code goes on
```

It may be that you didn't configure this system variable.

Since you installed via pip, and probalby didn't touch te setup.py file, I recommend you to do the following:
1-) Uninstall the package, and delete the build directories
2-) Set JAVA_HOME variable following [this](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/setting-java-home-variable-in-windows/)
3-) Download JPype manually from [github](https://github.com/originell/jpype) and install it using `python setup.py install`

Good luck, tell me if it works

Comment: It looks like this is the problem. I've got as far as compiling now - Its trying to build _jpype but I don't have a C++ compiler installed (yet).

Comment: Nice! Glad for helping. Look for MinGW for C/C++ compilers

Comment: The JAVA_HOME setting link is broken in the answer. You can set JAVA_HOME on Windows as "set JAVA_HOME=C:\my\path\with spaces\to\jdk". You should also do "set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin" if not done already by the installer. On *nix "export JAVA_HOME=/my/path/to/java" and "export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin"